# Calculate Percentages of total in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

How to calculate the % of total just like we use in excel to shows the counts into %.

Plz refer attached screen shot, i need % wise display instead of numeric.

[image]

Below is my SQL query:

```
SELECT
[Region]=ISNULL(zone, 'Grand Total'),
[chennai]=SUM([chennai]),
[Kandivali]=SUM([Kandivali]),
[kolhapur]=SUM([kolhapur])
from
(select zone,[Ret#Location]
from [Test].[dbo].[dailyAssure_1]
) src
pivot
(count([Ret#Location])
for [Ret#Location] in ([chennai], [Kandivali], [kolhapur])
) piv
Group by ROLLUP(zone);
```

Comment: Pretty sure you could simply divide by the number of rows. SUM(chennai) / Count(*) If that isn't going to work then you need to provide some details for us. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Agree with above comment but then you would need to format or cast the calculation results to keep the formatting of each value the same.

Comment: The sum of the first column (chennai) appears to be 104.82 and not 100, is this correct?

Comment: Andrea : The east % is 0.27 in chennai not a 4%, my mistake,sorry

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit of a hack, but something similar to this would probably work...

```
with 
    data as (
        -- this is your query
        SELECT  [Region]=zone,
                [chennai]=SUM([chennai]),
                [Kandivali]=SUM([Kandivali]),
                [kolhapur]=SUM([kolhapur])
        from    (select zone, [Ret#Location] from [Test].[dbo].[dailyAssure_1]) src
        pivot
        (count([Ret#Location]) for [Ret#Location] in ([chennai], [Kandivali], [kolhapur]) ) piv
        Group by ROLLUP(zone)
    ) ,
    totals as (
        -- one row with totals for chennai, etc...
        select  zone='Grand Total', 
                chennai=sum(chennai), 
                kandivali=sum(kandivali), 
                kolhapur=sum(kolhapur)
        from    data
    )
select  d.zone ,
        d.chennai / t.chennai as chennai ,
        d.kandivali/ t.kandivali as kandvali ,
        d.kolhapur / t.kolhapur as kolhapur
from    data d
cross join totals t
;
```

It doesn't include a total row (which is all 1's anyway), and you may need to cast the values used in the % calculation (or the % value itself) to get the desired output format.

Comment: BoCoKeith : Getting Error as Incorrect syntax near ')'. near data d, plz check

Comment: It's difficult for me to take this much further since I cannot actually execute the query without access to your data and schema.  I verified that the query parses correctly in SSMS.  What version of SQL are you using?